# How to use user defined function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a function, now i want to use that function in my query. I have two in parameters to pass in the function. How can i use that query in my function

Comment: Step 1: Check [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/).

Comment: In general `SELECT my_function(param1, param2);`. If you need more details, please paste some code.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me